# Get data of Column which is maintain in other table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two table which has data as below

```
Table1
    lblNumber   Column1
    lblName     Column2

Table2
     Column1     Column2   Column3
     Value1      Value2    Value3
```

i want data in the below format

```
RequiredResult
    lblNumber   Value1      
    lblName     Value2
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: does table 2 will have only one row (tuple) ?

Comment: No Table1 has only one row but Table2 can hs multiple row i have relation between those two table

Comment: ok then what is the requiredResult when you have more than one row in table2?

Comment: Multiple result give me problem i will happy even i get single record

Comment: @SagarChavan Could you, please, add sample data for both tables, and the expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are happy with any single result from Table2. Does this help?

Select A.column1FromA,B.column2FromB from Table1 A 
left join 
(select column1FromB,MAX(column2FromB) as column2FromB column from Table2 
group by column1FromB
) B
on A.column2FromA = B.column1FromB